# How to integrate Plaid Link into a Kivy app?

Tags: android, kivy, currency, kivymd, plaid

I am building a money app with Kivy and KivyMD, and i need to use Plaid to manage the transactions. Is it possible to integrate Plaid into a Kivy app ?

I expect to integrate Plaid Link into my Kivy app. https://plaid.com/demo/
I am open for suggestions. Thanks !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.